# Changing lstlisting firstnumber within tabular

Tags: tables, listings

Using just `lstlisting` at the document level, I am easily able to continue from the previous line number series:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
int main() {
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=last]
return 0; }
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image: document level]

However, if I try to do the same thing inside a table, it fails to build:

```
\begin{figure*}
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    \begin{lstlisting}
    int main() {
    \end{lstlisting}\\
    %
    \begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=last]
    return 0; }
    \end{lstlisting}
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure*}
```

For comparison, the same markup passes the build without the `firstnumber=last`:

```
\begin{figure*}
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    \begin{lstlisting}
    int main() {
    \end{lstlisting}\\
    %
    \begin{lstlisting}
    return 0; }
    \end{lstlisting}
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure*}
```

[image: in a table]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ 
    numbers=left
}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
int main() {
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=last]
return 0; }
\end{lstlisting}


\begin{figure*}[h]
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    \begin{lstlisting}
    int main() {
    \end{lstlisting}\\
    %
    \begin{lstlisting}
    return 0; }
    \end{lstlisting}
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Include  the second `lstlisting` inside  a group work fine

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this by giving your `lstlisting` a name by assigning this command:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[name=john]
………
\end{lstlisting}
```

For more information, see section **5.6 Line numbers** of the documention for `listings` Note that you can always locate the documentation using the command-line/terminal by writing `texdoc listings`, and that works for any package. The documentation is also available at http://ctan.org/pkg/listings

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    numbers=left
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[name=john]
int main() {
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[name=john]
return 0; }
\end{lstlisting}


\begin{figure*}[h]
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    \begin{lstlisting}[name=jane]
    int main() {
    \end{lstlisting}\\
    %
    \begin{lstlisting}[name=jane]
    return 0; }
    \end{lstlisting}\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```